# Ubuntu CLI Mass Find CP

Tags: ubuntu, find, command-line-interface, cp

```
find /www/ -iname ".htaccess" -exec cp {} {}_cp \;
```

Will copy all of the .htaccess files and rename them to .htaccess_cp but what I would like to do is copy all of the .htaccess files on the site and put them in one directory. The problem is that they will all need to have a different name otherwise they would just overwrite eachother. Ideally I would like them to have the filename of the Parent directory.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
find /www -name '.htaccess' -exec bash -c 'newfile=${1}_cp; if [[ ! -e $newfile ]]; then
   cp "$1" "$newfile"
else 
   count=1 
   while true; do 
      if [[ ! -e ${1}_cp.$count ]]; do 
         cp "$1" "${1}_cp.$count" 
         break
      else 
         ((count++))
      fi
   done 
fi' -- {} \;
```

Comment: The only problem with that is it will append an incrementing number to the end but with say 30 sites on there each with a different .htaccess file i wouldn't know which .htaccess file goes with which site?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
for file in $(find /www/ -iname ".htaccess"); do  
    new_file_name=$(echo $file | sed 's#/#_#g')
    cp $file $new_file_name
done
```